# Why volumio.local was able to access the raspberry since it connected to local network

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, router, local-network

After setting up volumio on raspberry, an interest feature was that you can use 'volumio.local' as the address to access the webpage hosted by raspberry, and there was not much to worry whether the ip address changed every time the raspberry connected to the local network. I was wondering how did volumio do that and how to setup an custom address for an raspberry to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a system called **Bonjour**, which can locate devices and services on a local network using multicast Domain Name System (mDNS). See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)).